# Image not view on page in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

```
**NewController**
This is my **NewController** i going to fetch data from database but my image not view on my view page so i don't know how can i view image on my view page.
This is my **NewController** i going to fetch data from database but my image not view on my view page so i don't know how can i view image on my view page.
This is my **NewController** i going to fetch data from database but my image not view on my view page so i don't know how can i view image on my view page.
This is my **NewController** i going to fetch data from database but my image not view on my view page so i don't know how can i view image on my view page.
This is my **NewController** i going to fetch data from database but my image not view on my view page so i don't know how can i view image on my view page.

<?php


namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use AppBundle\Entity\Login;
use AppBundle\Entity\customer;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;




    class NewController extends Controller

    {

    /**
     * @Route("/main", name="main")
     */

    public function mainAction(Request $request)

    {

        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->findAll();


            return $this->render('website/main.html.twig', array('view' => $product));



    }

?>


**main.html.twig**
 This is my **main.html.twig** i don't know  how can i display my image from database on my view page.
```

This is my **main.html.twig** i don't know  how can i display my image from database on my view page. 
 This is my **main.html.twig** i don't know  how can i display my image from database on my view page. 
 This is my **main.html.twig** i don't know  how can i display my image from database on my view page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChzpF.jpg)

```
{% for key in view %}
<table border="1">
        <tr>

            <td>
                <img  src="{{ key.fileinput }}" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
            </td>
             <td>
                {{ key.productname }}
            </td>
             <td>
                {{ key.productprice }}
            </td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}


**Product.php**

This is my **Product.php**.

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="productname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $productname;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="productprice", type="integer")
     */
    private $productprice;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fileinput", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fileinput;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set productname
     *
     * @param string $productname
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setProductname($productname)
    {
        $this->productname = $productname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductname()
    {
        return $this->productname;
    }

    /**
     * Set productprice
     *
     * @param integer $productprice
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setProductprice($productprice)
    {
        $this->productprice = $productprice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productprice
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductprice()
    {
        return $this->productprice;
    }

    /**
     * Set fileinput
     *
     * @param string $fileinput
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setFileinput($fileinput)
    {
        $this->fileinput = $fileinput;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fileinput
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileinput()
    {
        return $this->fileinput;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you dump your `key.fileinput` ?

Comment: Sir i have used "<img  src="{{asset ("uploads/photos/" ~  key.fileinput)  }}" attr="" width="100" height="100" />" and its working

Answer (score 0):

Using `<img src="{{asset ("uploads/photos/" ~ key.fileinput) }}" attr="" width="100" height="100" />` worked... Using `<img src="{{asset ("uploads/photos/" ~ key.fileinput) }}" attr="" width="100" height="100" />` worked... Using `<img src="{{asset ("uploads/photos/" ~ key.fileinput) }}" attr="" width="100" height="100" />` worked...